# Execute A set of queries as Batch In AW Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, batch-processing, amazon-athena, aws-java-sdk

I'm trying to execute AWS Athena queries as batch using aws-java-sdk-athena. I'm able to establish the connection,run individually the queries, but no idea how to run 3 queries as batch. Any help appreciated.

Query

```
 1.select * from table1 limit 2
 2.select * from table2 limit 2
 3.select * from table3 limit 2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run multiple queries in parallel in Athena. They will be executed in background. So if you start your queries using e.g.

```
StartQueryExecutionResult startQueryExecutionResult = client.startQueryExecution(startQueryExecutionRequest);
```

you will get an `executionId`. This can be then used to query the status of the running queries to check if they finished already. You can get the execution status of the query using [`getQueryExecutionId`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/athena/AmazonAthena.html#getQueryExecution-com.amazonaws.services.athena.model.GetQueryExecutionRequest-) or [`batchGetQueryExecution`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/athena/AmazonAthena.html#batchGetQueryExecution-com.amazonaws.services.athena.model.BatchGetQueryExecutionRequest-).

#### Limits

There are some limits in Athena. You can run up to 20 SELECT queries in parallel.

See [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/service-limits.html):

> 20 DDL queries at the same time. DDL queries include CREATE TABLE and CREATE TABLE ADD PARTITION queries.
>
> 20 DML queries at the same time. DML queries include SELECT and CREATE TABLE AS (CTAS) queries.

Comment: is this also apply to inserts in Athena?